# Java Keypair Generation - Prime Size Error

Tags: java

I tried to run the below code . But I get the below error. I have gone through similar posts in the stackoverflow, but still couldn't find a solution. So, I thought this error might be specific to my environment and code. I use Jdk 1.6 on windows and below is my code. Plese help me if you can. Thanks in advance

```
    package com.siebel.WebService;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;


 public class ContactusClient {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {


      SR_spcWeb_spcService srv=new UNINServiceRequestWSLocator().getSR_spcWeb_spcService(new java.net.URL("https://crmsit.un.org/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&WSSOAP=1"));
       ((SR_spcWeb_spcServiceStub)srv).setUsername("username");
       ((SR_spcWeb_spcServiceStub)srv).setPassword("password");
       ((SR_spcWeb_spcServiceStub)srv).setHeader("http://siebel.com/webservices", "UsernameToken","username");
       ((SR_spcWeb_spcServiceStub)srv).setHeader("http://siebel.com/webservices", "PasswordText","password");
       ((SR_spcWeb_spcServiceStub)srv).setHeader("http://siebel.com/webservices", "SessionType","Stateless");
       QuerySR_Input sr=new QuerySR_Input("RFS-1-339103333");
       QuerySR_Output srvo= srv.querySR(sr);
}



}
```

I am getting the below error

```
       Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
        faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
         faultSubcode: 
         faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLException:      java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
          faultActor: 
          faultNode: 
          faultDetail: 
        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLException:    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at  org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
         at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
            at  org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
        at        org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
         at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at  com.siebel.WebService.SR_spcWeb_spcServiceStub.querySR(SR_spcWeb_spcServiceStub. java:255)
       at com.siebel.WebService.ContactusClient.main(ContactusClient.java:19)
       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.&lt;init&gt;(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
         at  com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
         ... 17 more
         Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime  size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
            at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DashoA13*..)
            at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? "`Prime  size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)`"

Comment: Yes What does that mean?